# SQL Server error 31 - "Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed", in an AWS Lambda function

Tags: sql-server, aws-lambda, tls1.2, .net-8.0, microsoft-data-sqlclient

I have an AWS Lambda function (REST Api), which has been running for years, that just queries a stored procedure on a remote SQL Server. I wanted to make some changes to it and took the opportunity to update the code, since its target framework is .NET Core 2.1.

So I created a new C# project targeting .NET 8.0 and using the 'Lambda ASP.NET Core Web Minimal API' template. By the way, I had a hard time getting it to work, but I finally did it thanks to this article: [Building Serverless .NET Minimal API (using Controller) with AWS Lambda](https://abdullahilgaz.com/blog/2022/11/04/building-serverless-net-minimal-api-using-controller-with-aws-lambda/).

But now I get this exception when I try to connect to my SQL Server:

> **A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)**

With this inner exception:

> **System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.**

In the research I've done, almost everywhere says this exception has to do with using TLS 1.2 to connect to SQL Server. I have tried many solutions but without success.

This is the SQL Server environment (it is hosted on a local cloud server provider):

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter (64-bit) SP1 (version 6.1 build 7601)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012
- Exposed via an HTTP URL (we don't have HTTPS option there)

And this is the connection string I'm using:
`$"Data Source={serverUrl};Initial Catalog={database};User ID={username};Password={pwd};"`

Things I've tried so far:

1. Updated SQL Server 2012 from SP3 to SP4 (version `11.0.7507` now).
2. Enabled TLS 1.2 in Database server via RegEdit ([TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server)).
3. Added `TrustServerCertificate=True`, `Encrypt=False` and `MultiSubnetFailover=True` in the connection string.
4. Changed from `System.Data.SqlClient` (version 4.8.6) to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` (version 5.2.0).

**-- EDIT 1 --**

After some exchange of information with users [AlwaysLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122/alwayslearning) and [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) in the comments section, I've tried capturing more information using WireShark at the server, so I'll post some screenshots of that. I've used `tcp port 1433` as a capture filter, and then I've used `ssl` as display filter.

When I execute the old AWS Lambda function (running on .NET Core 2.1), it communicates with the server using TLS v1.2 already, and it works:

[image: Wiresharking old function 1]

[image: Wiresharking old function 2]

But when I execute the new AWS Lambda function (running on .NET 8.0), it also communicates using TLS v1.2, but it's a bit different, at first it says it's TLSv1, but inside the message it says it's TLS v1.2 also:

[image: Wiresharking new function 1]

[image: Wiresharking new function 2]

And there are some extensions (marked in yellow) that were not used in the call that it's working:

[image: Wiresharking new function 3]

I guess some of those are the problem, maybe `psk_key_exchange_modes` and `key_share`?
Is it expecting some kind of key that I don't have?

**-- EDIT 2 --**

Looking at the `Server Hello` message that's exchanged between client and server when the old function is executed, it seems that `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)` was the Cipher Suite used in the handshake protocol:

[image: Wiresharking old function 3]

Those are the Cipher Suites listed in the `Client Hello` message when the old function is executed:

[image: Wiresharking old function 4]

When the new function is executed, this Cipher Suite (`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)`) is not listed in the `Client Hello` message:

[image: Wiresharking new function 4]

Comment: Have you checked HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers and HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphersuites to ensure that the ciphers or ciphersuites needed for TLS 1.2 operation haven't all been disabled? Does the server also expose public HTTPS web services... have you checked their operation with Qualys SSL Labs (for example)?

Comment: Aside... your upgrade schedule seems to have fallen behind for this server. Extended support for Windows Server 2008 R2 ended back in 2020.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I just checked and there is nothing under the `Ciphers` and `ChipherSuites` keys. As I mentioned, this server doesn't have an HTTPS endpoint, just HTTP. I didn't know about Qualys SSL Labs, just ran a test, it says the certificate is not trusted, but says that TLS 1.2 is configured and it passed all the handshake simulation via TLS 1.2.

Comment: @Charlieface, no, just checked that the server is version 6.1 Build 7601, Service Pack 1, I'm downloading SP2 now.

Comment: The issue isn't the HTTP endpoint (that's a webserver thing), the issue is that SQL Server itself is doing an encrypted connection and failing, probably because of a cipher mismatch. Use Wireshark to check what's happening with the Server and Client Hello.

Comment: @Charlieface you're right that HTTPS isn't an issue for the Lambda connection - I was wanting to establish that the 2008 R2 server had TLS 1.2 configured correctly. That the HTTPS tests work and TDS doesn't suggests perhaps that there's something going on with ciphersuites at the Lambda end.

Comment: @Charlieface, I don't know exactly how to use Wireshark to check what you suggested, but I'm researching it. I already installed Wireshark and read somewhere that I have to filter `ssl`. But, how do I start this communication between client and server, to capture it with Wireshark? And, I can do it from my machine, but the connection between my machine and the remote SQL Server is fine. The problem is the Lambda function connecting to SQL Server, but I can't run Wireshark on the AWS Lambda function. So, how can I check it?

Comment: Actually, the problem is the new AWS Lambda function, with .NET 8, connecting to my SQL Server, because the old AWS Lambda function, with .NET Core 2.1, also connects just fine with my SQL Server.

Comment: Could AWS Lamba be executing the code in a Docker container using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0`? Could be related to OpenSSL changes in Debian 12 upon which that image is based. Ref: [dotnet 8: Error Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed) #2252](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/2252) Have a read through the `openssl.cnf` changes mentioned to see if that helps.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I read about this problem with OpenSSL and the solution in a few places before posting my question, but I don't think I have that kind of control in Lambda. Of course, I could upload my own container image (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-deploy-functions.html) and that way I could have more control, but , I don't want to go through all this work to put a simple function online.... Today I'm just sending a .ZIP file with my compiled project, and I wanted to try to solve it using this approach.

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for the advice! I ran Wireshark on my cloud server and ran the Lambda function. I filtered using `tcp port 1433` in the capture, and then filtered using `ssl` in the captured data. I found the `Client Hello` message, filtered all messages with source and destination matching the IP number of the Lambda function. `Client Hello` started as TLS 1.0 and "turned into" TLS 1.2. According to this article https://www.catchpoint.com/blog/wireshark-tls-handshake, a `Server Hello` should have occurred in response to `Client Hello`, which didn't happen, but I can't identify why .

Comment: Probably the server doesn't support TLS1.2 even though you claim it does. Double check all updates are installed, and double-check registry settings. Better yet, upgrade that ancient Windows Server installation to something modern.

Comment: @Charlieface, I've added some screenshots to the question, showing my Wireshark captures. Also, I made a mistake about the windows server version, mine is already at the latest build. There is Windows Server 2008, that's equivalent to Windows Vista, and goes until SP2, and there is Windows Server 2008 R2, that's equivalent to Windows 7, and goes until SP1. Mine is the R2 version and was already with SP1 installed.

Comment: R2 SP1 still needs more updates to enable TLS1.2, as well as registry settings https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows-server-2008-sp2-windows-embedded-posready-2009-and-windows-embedded-standard-2009-b6ab553a-fa8f-3f5e-287c-e752eb3ce5f4 or you can use the free IIS Crypto tool to enable it. Can we see the Server Hello from the Wireshark trace as well, and we need to see if they both client and server support a common TLS version and a common cipher in the Cipher Suite list.

Comment: The link you sent me is about 2008 and not 2008 R2. Anyway, I've already added those registry keys mentioned in the article, as I said in the original question. I'll add those information to the question, thanks.

Comment: "this Cipher Suite (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)) is not listed in the Client Hello message:" but what about the Server Hello, is there a matching one anywhere in the list? We don't need to see the *working* TLS trace just the not working one, so just delete that.

Comment: When the new function is executed, the server receives the `Client Hello` message but doesn't send a `Server Hello` in response, it just responds with a `[FIN, ACK]`. By the way, I've installed the update from KB 3140245,, as you suggested, and added the `DefaultSecureProtocols` registry subkey, but still the same results.

Comment: It still sounds to me that TLS1.2 is disabled. Did you use the IIS Crypto tool https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download

Comment: I used IIS Crypto, yesterday I think. But the problem was related to the absence of a certificate, it is working now. I posted an answer explaining what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I discovered that it is unusual that in a TLS handshake process the server receives a `Client Hello` message from the client and just ends the "conversation" abruptly with a `[FIN, ACK]` message, rather than a `Server Hello` response or an alert message demonstrating any problem that may have occurred when parsing the `Client Hello` message.

Then I read somewhere that this unusual behavior could be caused by some issue with the Cipher Suites or some issue related to the certificate. I didn't have a certificate on the server, so I started wondering if that could be the problem. So I searched for a way to use the free TLS certificate generator [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) with SQL Server and found this article:

- [Encrypting SQL Server connections with Let’s Encrypt certificates](https://sqlsunday.com/2017/11/22/encrypting-tds-with-letsencrypt/)
  (by Daniel Hutmacher, in 2017)

And this other article also has some good advice on how to configure a TLS certificate in SQL Server:

- [Enable TLS on SQL Server](https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-tls-on-sql-server/)
  (by Surender Kumar, in 2022)

After installing the TLS certificate on the server and associating it with SQL Server, the connection to SQL Server in the new AWS Lambda function started working!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error very similar to this from an AWS Lambda function.  My error was:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
```

I noticed that the error seemed to originate from here within the call stack:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.EnableSsl(UInt32 info, SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean integratedSecurity, String serverCertificateFilename)
```

I found that when I added the following to the end of my connection string the error went away:

```
TrustServerCertificate=true;Encrypt=true
```

Comment: I tried changing the `TrustServerCertificate` and `Encrypt` properties in the connection string, but in my case it didn't work. I tried `Encrypt=False`, because since `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` version 4.0.0, the default value for this option is `true` (https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/release-notes/4.0/4.0.0.md#breaking-changes), so setting it to `true` doesn't change anything, this is already the default behavior.